# How to find out what values for h and k have infinitely many solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

In this problem, I need to find out for which values of h and k are there infinitely many solutions. How would I go about solving the problem. I first started out by turning it into a matrix and dividing the first row by five in order to get a leading one in the upper left corner. Where would i go from that point on. Also, if anyone is familiar with videos or websites that are relevant to THIS SPECIFIC problem, could you please let me know (all the videos aren't relevant to this problem where the variables are not the answers to the equations).

```
5X1 + 3X2 = -1
HX1 + KX2 = 2
```

Sorry for my poor formatting, first time posting on math.stack

Comment: Why exactly do you want a video that solves this specific problem? Learn the method.

Answer (score 0):

Two linear equations in two unknowns have infinitely many solutions when one is a constant multiple of the other, because then the two equations say the same thing, so you really only have one equation.

With that hint, can you solve the problem?

Comment: YESSIR!! :) thanks!